# python dictionary .get() method with default value throws exception even when it should not even be executed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a dictionary that I would like to retrieve some values from using .get() method and if the key is not present, a default function should be executed that returns the correct value but it should only be executed if the key is not present.

I tried removing the default value and it works, so why does the function gets executed even if it won't be used?

The SQL query will return nothing because it only contains values not already in the dict

```py
def get_port():

    def default():
        cursor.execute("SELECT port FROM table WHERE server=%s LIMIT 1",(server_name,))
        return cursor.fetchone()[0]

    port = {
        'server1': 2222,
        'server2': 2223,
        'server3': 2224
        }
    #print(port.get(server_name)) << Works
    return port.get(server_name, default())
```

Error:

> return cursor.fetchone()[0] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not
>   subscriptable

I expect the default function to only execute if key is not present..

Comment: Because of Python's evaluation order, before it even calls the `get` function, it needs to know with what arguments to call it. So it evaluates the arguments first. Because the secod argument is `default()` (mind the `()`), the function is actually gets called in that moment. That's the reason, the solution is in the answers :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the issue with `get` with a default value which needs build/evaluation is that the code is executed, even if not needed, which can slow down the code, or in your case trigger unnecessary errors.

An alternative could be:

```
port.get(server_name) or default()
```

If `get` returns `None` because a key is not found, then `or default()` is activated. But if `get` returns something, it short-circuits and `default()` is not called.

(this could fail if `get` returned empty string, zero, any "falsy" value but in your case - a server name - I'll suppose that it cannot happen)

Another option (maybe overkill here) would be to use a `collections.defaultdict` object

```
port = collections.defaultdict(default)
port.update({
        'server1': 2222,
        'server2': 2223,
        'server3': 2224
        })
```

Then each call to `port[server]` with an unknown key calls the `default` function and stores the result in the dictionary. Make `port` global or persistent and you have a created nice cache: next time the same value is fetched the default is already in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the function, so it does get executed (`default()` vs. `default`). (Even if you didn't call it, i.e. `.get(..., default)`, you'd then just get the function object back, which doesn't suit your purposes.)

If you only want to call it when the key does not exist, you need to be slightly more verbose – and at that point, it's worth refactoring like so:

```py
ports = {
    "server1": 2222,
    "server2": 2223,
    "server3": 2224,
}


def get_port(server_name):
    port = ports.get(server_name)
    if not port:
        cursor.execute(
            "SELECT port FROM table WHERE server=%s LIMIT 1",
            (server_name,),
        )
        port = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return port
```

Comment: so if I used default instead of default() I would only get the function object when the key is not found?

Comment: Exactly so. There's no function that would call the `default` function on miss.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer will bring the solution to your current problem/question.

> `default()` is being evaluated at first.

I want to include some more info to help you *understand* what is happening. The question may look naive, but it touches fundamental aspects of Python (and any programming language actually). Hopefully, that will have some interest to some readers.

The first misunderstood aspect is related to [eager evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation). Python is an eager evaluator. [Here is a nice post](https://swizec.com/blog/python-and-lazy-evaluation/swizec/5148) *around* the topic.

Then, read about the [get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method itself -- it returns a *value*, which may be a function since functions are [first class objects](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/first-class-functions-python/) in Python.